# FTP in and out of Acumatica

Tags: acumatica

I am trying to integrate Acumatica with an interfacing system and I need to be able to send and receive data in xml format, say for example one is Customer info, that should be sent to the interfacing system.

For some reasons, we ruled out the Import/ Export scenarios and we need to achieve the interface using FTP.

I'm unable to find much info online on how to FTP data in and out of Acumatica. So if anyone can share links to some documentation, it will be very helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as you want to be able to send and receive data in an XML format, you might want to check the Web Service options.

There are two possibilities, the Contract Based SOAP API and the Screen Based SOAP API. Both of these are sending SOAP request in XML format.

If you are starting a new project, Acumatica is suggesting you use either version of the Contract Based API (SOAP or REST). So your best bet is probably in looking at Contract Based SOAP API.

As there is not much information on the structure behind what is being sent you will probably have to create yourself project in c# first and inspect the structure of the package being sent to the server hosting the Acumatica instance so that you can reproduce it using your own FTP Interface.

Answer (score 0):

You need to work with .Net native `FtpWebRequest` class. You can find more information at [MSDN FtpWebRequest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebrequest(v=vs.110).aspx).